# ufw firewall rule, beginner question

Tags: networking, ufw, routing

Maybe a stupid question but nevertheless

If your computer only has one IP address of 207.15.15.15, (IP addresses and protocols are just to make it more concrete), is there then any difference between these two commands?

```
sudo ufw allow from 95.95.95.95 to any port 80 proto TCP

sudo ufw allow from 95.95.95.95 to 207.15.15.15 port 80 proto TCP
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me take a little more technical side to this.  Consider that `ufw` is just a user-friendly(ish) front-end to the underlying `netfilter`/`iptables` system built into the kernel.

That in mind, let's read your rules in an `iptables` perspective.

Your first rule would be this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -s 95.95.95.95 -j ACCEPT
```

Your second rule would be this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -s 95.95.95.95 -d 207.15.15.15 -j ACCEPT
```

At their core, though, they both accept port 80 over the TCP protocol from 95.95.95.95.  The only difference is you specify the destination IP address in the filter.

If your system only has one IP address that is public-facing, and your system isn't behind a router or NAT, then the rules are identical.  That is, assuming your IP address of 207.15.15.15 stays the same all the time.  If the IP address changes, then the second rule you entered will no longer operate properly.

However, if your system is behind NAT, then you should *not* use the second method, which designates the target IP address, because your NAT'd system will not properly read the packets in a way that it would match the 'ACCEPT' rule.  In that case, you should only use the first one.  (Because NAT rewrites the destination of the packet to the internal IP address, so instead of 207.15.15.15 your system will see a destination of 192.168.6.6 for example, so the extra 'destination' match you added will prevent the ACCEPT of the packet.)

Essentially, unless you're running multiple IP addresses and different services on each with different ports and rulesets, you don't really need to specify the 'destination' IP address in your `ufw` rule with the `to 207.15.15.15` part.